# Sound over HDMI not working any more after waking up from suspend

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, hdmi

So far, suspending to ram and waking up from it works. My laptop's external display (connected via HDMI) works, too.

However, what doesn't work is the sound, which works before suspending, of course. I'm using my external monitor's speakers and have made the corresponding settings in Ubuntu's sound menu (switched to "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input" in "Hardware" tab).

What can I do to fix it?

**Edit**: when I ran ubuntu-bug, it tested sound output with and without using pulse. Without pulse, it worked, however I still heard the noise. With pulse it was only noise.

**Edit**: works fine with natty and oneiric now. Updating to latest Ubuntu solves the problem.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo killall -9 pulseaudio` from the command line?

Comment: yes but it doesn't kill pulseaudio. When I log out and log back in, it does kill pulse but it doesn't help either.

Comment: Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log.  Be sure to follow both procedures before suspend (from a fresh boot) and after resume. Please then attach the requested information in your question.

Comment: I'm running 11.10 same problem here. I have to restart to get sound working on HDMI. On windows I had no such issue.

Answer (score 3):

Hardware malfunctioning after suspend sounds like a driver bug to me. `ubuntu-bug -s audio`

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can try `sudo alsa force-reload` to force your drivers to unload and reload (will kill all running sound apps in the process though).

Comment: I'd add to Mackenzie's response that normally it's a driver issue such that we can hack around a hardware issue, but sometimes it's also a hardware issue that **can't** be worked around.  Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/InstallingLinuxAlsaDriverModules.

Comment: Thanks Maco for your suggestion but I'm afraid it didn't help at all. However, when I run the audio testing it does play sound without pulse. With pulse, however, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Determine which kernel module is handling HDMI audio.  On my XBMC box, it is "snd_hda_codec_nvhdmi", then unload that module before the laptop sleeps via a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d.  The command "lsmod | grep hdmi" may give you some clues.  You may have to unload more than one module for this to work properly (like "snd"), but if you can find the right combination, it will be just like you shutdown and rebooted each time you sleep your laptop.

Here is what your script should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Script to disable hdmi audio before suspend and restart after wake.

case "${1}" in
        suspend|hibernate)
            rmmod snd_hda_codec_nvhdmi
            rmmod snd
                ;;
        resume|thaw)
            modprobe snd
            modprobe snd_hda_codec_nvhdmi
                ;;
esac
```

Comment: Hi,I tried it but I'm afraid it didn't work either. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me when HDMI sound is "unavailable / unplugged" after waking up

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --set "audio" on
```

YMMV, adapt to your HDMI output name.