# Intel DHA no audio on HDMI: works only after display sleep

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, intel-nuc

I have an Intel NUC (NUC7i3BNH, i.e., using Intel High Definition Audio) running Ubuntu 16.04.3. Its intended use is for a media center. I'm unable to get HDMI audio working unless I allow the system to sit idle (5 minutes by default) long enough for the display to sleep. When the display is woken back up, HDMI audio works perfectly.

Pavucontrol has no effect on the issue. Full system suspend does not fix HDMI audio. I've tried multiple displays, same behavior with each.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: That's weird. It seems HDMI was not projected 'to sleep'. Look this unsolved [2010-issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7645/sound-over-hdmi-not-working-any-more-after-waking-up-from-suspend). Even on [Windows](https://community.amd.com/thread/190412?start=0&tstart=0) we see complains about it!

Comment: Same issue with Zotac CI549.

Comment: Not an elegant solution but forcing a screen resolution as explained here https://askubuntu.com/questions/906266/hdmi-audio-only-when-display-resolution-change?rq=1 worked for me without having to wait for the go to Sleep. I hope I could automate it

Comment: Maybe it's just a matter of selecting the right output? Check if my answer here fixes your problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1024739/204815

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: This is fixed in kernel 4.14 and higher.

I have a NUC too (NUC7i5BNK) and this has been a pain.

You can force the display to sleep with `/usr/bin/xset dpms force off` command.

I included this line in the required startup script and fixed for my purposes (run as an emulation station, running RetroPie).

RetroPie usually launch stuff using a script called `/opt/retropie/supplementary/runcommand/runcommand.sh`, so I've edited this script.

If you want to use Kodi, edit Kodi startup script and before launch it include these 2 lines:

```
xset dpms force off
xset dpms force on
```